# Create a Redirect with additional query params for another plugin

Tags: typo3, extbase, tx-news

I use the news plugin where I add an another Plugin (lets call it 'Form') as a CE für the Detail view.

When I fill out the Form in the Detail view and submit it, then my redirect inside my Controller only passes the Arguments for my Extension.

`$this->redirect('success');`

But I would like that he also pass the Arguments for the News extensions, so that I land at the Details view of the news and my Form plugin gets his other action informations from the redirect.

But as far as I can see, the redirect method only takes arguments for one plugin.

Did anyone have an Idea?

Answer (score 0):

The `redirect` function only allows arguments for the controller/action you are redirecting to. There is no way to add other get parameters.

The only way to do this is to create the URL yourself and use the `redirectToUri` function. That would make it something like:

```
$uriBuilder = $this->getControllerContext()->getUriBuilder();
$uri = $uriBuilder->reset()
  ->setTargetPageUid(1)
  ->setArguments($newsArgs) 
  ->uriFor('success');
$this->redirectToUri($uri);
```

Comment: OK, but wouldn't it make problems with the cHash parameter?

Comment: It shouldn't. The cHash is calculated based on all parameters, so both the ones for your plugin and the extra ones you add for the news extension.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to @Rudy Gnodde answer:

The uriBuilder has an option "addQueryString", equal to the typolink function from typoscript. If this option is enabled it attach the configured query strings to the url. This way you dont need to address each parameter for each extension:

```
$uriBuilder = $this->getControllerContext()->getUriBuilder();
$uri = $uriBuilder->reset()
  ->setAddQueryString(true)
  ->setAddQueryStringMethod('GET')
  ->uriFor('success');
$this->redirectToUri($uri);
```

For the form ViewHelper `f:form` you should add the option `addQueryString="true"`, too!